# Multiple Posted Types asp.net 5 MVC 6 API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I can use [FromBody] for single type , but is there any way to use multiple?

From the searching and reading I've done there is not a way, but i don't know if a way has been added in MVC 6.

If not, where would be best to start with custom way.

What should i be researching and looking for best method or place to hook in just before model binding so i can include my own method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is to create a composite wrapper:

```
public class Wrapper
{
   public ModelA A { get; set; }

   public ModelB B { get; set; }
}
```

Put Wrapper in the parameter list and mark that `[FromBody]`.  You can't use that attribute more than once because all of the contents of the body are assumed to match the parameter type.

Comment: Is there no way to hook into same functions used by FromBody? and split the body into say two tag values like post values, and then do something like  . [FromBody("ModelA")] ModelA A,  [FromBody("ModelB")] ModelB B?

Comment: Searched all over to see if there was solution, there seems some close but nothing concrete.  so marking as solution... anyone looking for further reading... http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/08/Passing-multiple-POST-parameters-to-Web-API-Controller-Methods comes close but needs updating to asp.net 5 mvc 6 and http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/may/08/passing-multiple-post-parameters-to-web-api-controller-methods might be usful.

Comment: If you don't use [FromBody], there are possibilities of having more than one value.  If you do use FromBody, Dave Ward indicated you can only have one, which he said "Speaking of the parameters to our method, another potentially confusing thing about accepting [FromBody] parameters is that there can be only one." from http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

Answer (score 5):

The composite wrapper approach is great if you can easily share your model between the caller and server, but a more generic approach is to use JObject:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;  // this gets you to JObject

[Route("svc/[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
  [HttpPost("{accountid}")]
  public IActionResult UpdateAccount(int accountid, [FromBody]JObject payload)
  {
    var loginToken = payload["logintoken"].ToObject<LoginToken>();
    var newAccount = payload["account"].ToObject<Account>();
    // perform update
    return this.Ok("success");
  }
}
```

You could probably also go with a `Tuple` which would give you the concrete types specified in the parameter list. This would be great if your clients were always .NET apps (.NET 4.0 or later, specifically) but you'd probably want to write a helper library to get the right wire format if you were trying to come from AJAX or something similar.